# Coroutine problem(I think)

Tags: unity, c#

I've developed a loading system that uses coroutines. When I load up the game and hit 'new' or 'continue' game works fine and it loads up the game just as it should. However, when I go back to the menu none of them work. It doesn't seem like the coroutine gets past the yield return new WaitForSeconds(1). I honestly don't understand why this is happening and I can't seem to find any information to help me.

Here's the code I have:

```
    private IEnumerator LoadLevel() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);//doesn't get past here when i try to reload

    ao = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CurrentSceneToLoad"));
    ao.allowSceneActivation = false;

    while (!ao.isDone) {
        RadialLoad.fillAmount = ao.progress;
        if (ao.progress == 0.9f) {
            RadialLoad.fillAmount = 1;

            loadingText.text = "Press any key to continue...";

            if (Input.anyKey) {
                ao.allowSceneActivation = true;
            }
        }
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("CurrentSceneToLoad");
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

That's all of the relevant code basically the sequence of events is:

I start the game and then I load into the first level and everything works as expected. When I go back to the menu. Using the same code as above and then try to load into the first level again it no longer gets past the the  first return waitforseconds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard for us to help you diagnose the problem unless you show us your code. Please try to create a minimal sample that demonstrates the issue, editing your question to include only the code required for us to reproduce the problem ourselves. That way we can investigate the problem in detail and help you track down the issue.

Comment: Okay, that's fine I just updated the question thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: Remember, a minimal, complete, verifiable example must include all of the code a stranger would need to reproduce your problem. The code you've posted relies on values set in PlayerPrefs, but does not include the code that sets these values. It does not show what calls LoadLevel either. These should be clear signs that you have not yet provided a full picture of the situation you're asking about, which means we're in the dark, guessing what the rest looks like. In particular, does any of your code modify Time.timeScale? This can cause WaitForSeconds to take longer/forever (if set to 0).

Comment: If it works the first time and not the second, it probably means you're not resetting a variable used in one of your conditions. Attach the debugger, check out your variables. Look into `ao.progress == 0.9f` too, that's questionable because you're use the equality comparator with a float.

Comment: The coroutine is called when the player pressed the new or continue button. I've checked if the coroutine is called so the problem isn't there. I've also checked if the data saved in the PlayerPref is correct and it is. So, it can only mean that the problem is within the coroutine itself. Thanks, Byte, I'll have a look at the various variables. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @DMGregory I had set the time.timeScale to 0 previously and completely forget to set it back to 1 when I was loading back into the menu. Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to set Time.TimeScale back to 1 after I set it to 0 to pause the game whilst in the menu.